# I am trying to copy the element number from one array to the output of the other array in java

Tags: java, arrays

Whenever I print the output it comes out as `0`.

```
 for (k=0;k < records.length - 1; k++) { // stores number in new array
        if ( records[k] == maxWins) {
            for (i=0; i < winners.length - 1; i++) {
                    winners[i] = k;
            }
        }
    } // end of storing
```

I have already declared and initialized the proper variables. If you need more information I will gladly provide it.

Comment: What is your usecase? What is the input and desired output?

Comment: [mcve] please so we can reproduce the code and the problem

Comment: I don't see any output there. What do you output?

Comment: Your array bounds are very suspicious. Why do you go up to length - 1 instead of length?

Comment: What is this intended to ***do***?

Answer (score 0):

Changing to below code should work for you :

```
int i = 0;
 for (k=0;k < records.length; k++) { 
        if ( records[k] == maxWins) { 
                  winners[i] = k; // you want to store one winner one time only, 
                                  // so dont use another loop inside this loop
                  i++;
        }
    }
```

Screenshot:

[image]
[image]

> Code Improvement:
>
> Don't use an array for winners as that can be at
> different point of times. Instead, use a list and convert it into an
> array when you are done with adding values.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to collect indices in the source array which has the same value as `maxWins` you can solve it like so,

```
List<Integer> winnerList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int k = 0; k < records.length; k++) { // stores number in new array
    if (records[k] == maxWins) {
        winnerList.add(k);
    }
}
```

Rather than using an array, you can use a dynamic data structure like a `List` for this. Using an array leads to lots of trailing zeros, and is counter productive since we don't know it's size ahead of time. You can easily convert the array into a `List` at the end.

```
winnerList.toArray();
```